# Ошибка в структурированных данных. Отсутствует символ "}" или название объекта

Tags: schema.org, микроразметка

```
</script>      
    
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@graph":[{"@type":"Product",
  "description":"Charly Chair by Montis and more contemporary designer furniture at Haute Living Website",
  "mainEntityOfPage":"https://haute-living.com/products/charly-chair",
  "name":"Charly Chair, Montis Charly Chair by Haute Living",
  "image": [
        "https://hauteliving.imgix.net/product-photos/cha1.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&bg=ffffffff&fit=fill&h=500&q=70&w=900&s=ed250b83f46996ba2ab7c5561d4579b0",
        "https://hauteliving.imgix.net/product-photos/cha2.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&bg=ffffffff&fit=fill&h=500&q=70&w=900&s=56bd0a3b7d0d6b020249ff57dc3c3e02",
        "https://hauteliving.imgix.net/product-photos/cha4.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&crop=focalpoint&fit=crop&fp-x=0.5&fp-y=0.5&h=1000&q=70&w=1800&s=48fe1556ec59de9c15180dee25101141",
        "https://hauteliving.imgix.net/product-photos/cha3.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&crop=focalpoint&fit=crop&fp-x=0.5&fp-y=0.5&h=1000&q=70&w=1800&s=1e096004e9577b7e2738d1c40d4caf8c"
    ],
            "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Montis"
    },
  "offers":{"@type":"Offer",
  "availability":"http://schema.org/PreOrder",
  "offeredBy":{"@id":"$DEFAULT_SITE_URL#identity"},
  "price":"0.00",
  "priceCurrency":"USD",
  "seller":{"@id":"$DEFAULT_SITE_URL#identity"},
  "url":"https://haute-living.com/products/charly-chair"},
  "sku":"3729","url":"https://haute-living.com/products/charly-chair"},
  {
          "@type": "OfferShippingDetails",
          "@id": "#shipping",
          "shippingRate": {
            "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
            "minValue": 7.49,
            "maxValue": 99.49,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "shippingDestination": {
            "@type": "DefinedRegion",
            "addressCountry": "US"
          },
          "deliveryTime": {
            "@type": "ShippingDeliveryTime",
            "handlingTime": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "minValue": 0,
              "maxValue": 3,
              "unitCode": "DAY"
          }
        }
    },  
  {
  "@id":"https://haute-living.com#identity",
  "@type":"LocalBusiness",
  "address":{"@type":"PostalAddress",
  "addressCountry":"United States",
  "addressLocality":"Chicago",
  "addressRegion":"IL",
  "postalCode":"60610",
  "streetAddress":"213 W Institute Pl"},
  "foundingLocation":"Chicago",
  "geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates",
  "latitude":"41.897190",
  "longitude":"-87.635210"},
  "image":{"@type":"ImageObject",
  "height":"555",
  "url":"https://website-craft.s3.amazonaws.com/spec-sheets/haute-living-modern-contemporary-furniture.jpg",
  "width":"556"},
  "logo":{"@type":"ImageObject",
  "height":"60",
  "url":"https://website-craft.s3.amazonaws.com/spec-sheets/_600x60_fit_center-center_82_none/602668/haute-living-modern-contemporary-furniture.png?mtime=1657047544",
  "width":"60"},
  
  "name":"Haute Living",
  "openingHoursSpecification":[{"@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
  "closes":"18:00:00",
  "dayOfWeek":["Monday"],
  "opens":"10:00:00"},
  {
  "@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
  "closes":"18:00:00","dayOfWeek":["Tuesday"],
  "opens":"10:00:00"},
  {
  "@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
  "closes":"18:00:00",
  "dayOfWeek":["Wednesday"],
  "opens":"10:00:00"},
  {
  "@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
  "closes":"18:00:00",
  "dayOfWeek":["Thursday"],
  "opens":"10:00:00"},
  {
  "@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
  "closes":"18:00:00",
  "dayOfWeek":["Friday"],
  "opens":"10:00:00"}],
  "priceRange":"$$$",
  "url":"https://haute-living.com"},
  {
  "@id":"#creator","@type":"Organization",
  "name":"Haute Living"},
  {
  "@type":"BreadcrumbList",
  "description":"Breadcrumbs list",
  "itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem",
  "item":"https://haute-living.com",
  "name":"Homepage","position":1},
  {
  "@type":"ListItem",
  "item":"https://haute-living.com/products/charly-chair",
  "name":"Charly Chair","position":2}],
  "name":"Breadcrumbs"
  }
  ]
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Прошу помощи в решении проблемы с микроразметкой. С уважением.

Comment: Напишите в любимом поисковике "json validator online", откройте любой понравившийся сайт ([например](https://jsonlint.com)), и вставьте туда все то, что вы написали в теге `<script>` (с `{` по `}`), ну и смотрите, какие ошибки вам выдаст валидатор. К примеру на строке 54 у вас лишняя запятая (некоторые считают такой JSON валидным), на строке 56 лишняя `}`, ну а на строке 57 и вовсе отсутствует запятая между `} {`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за конкретные указания, я SEO-специалист,а не программист, но с Вашей помощью все получилось! https://prnt.sc/rdVFfMI8Kn1c Красота)